# ability to see free/busy detail information for conference rooms in Outlook 2007 and Microsoft hosted Exchange solution

Tags: outlook-2007, hosted-exchange

recently my company migrated from an in-house Exchange server to the Microsoft hosted exchange online solution. My client is Outlook 2007. Before the migration, I could see the details of the meetings when I hovered on the busy blue bar for a resource such as a conference room. I could click on the meetings and see the invite list and the contents of the meeting. Ofcourse if the meeting was marked as private I could not. 
however after the migration to the online solution, I cannot see the detailed information. I can still see if the room is busy or not but I can no longer see the details of that meeting. The IT folks can see the information and they claim that they can see it because they have full admin rights. It is their claim that in the hosted Exchange solution you can either have full access (admin access) and see the details or not see anything but just that the room is busy. there is no middle ground such as being able to see the details of the meeting but not having any admin rights. For some reason I believe this to be not true.
Can someone please verify my doubts and inform me of what needs to be done to see that information if my IT folks are wrong?

thanks

Comment: This site really isn't that well suited for asking questions like this.  This site really is for questions from system admins to system admins.  You, and consequently us are so far remote from the actual configuration of the systems that it is hard to give you a useful answer.  Under some conditions Exchange/Outlook may operate the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It would all depend on how your hosting company has configured the permissions and what options they present.  Your IT staff will know how your hosting company has configured your Exchange environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask your IT guys to refer following article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546814.aspx

Microsoft Clearly mentioned that hosted exchange does have benefit of showing free/busy schedules.  You can also check following article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397225(EXCHG.80).aspx